# How to pipe a file as input to tar command

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, tar, git

I get the following error when trying to uncompress piped tar file with the following command :

```
$ git archive --format=tar 0af62b1 | tar -xf -C /the/path/here/
tar: -C: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

The first part `git archive --format=tar 0af62b1` outputs a tar file, printed on the screen. This output can be captured in a file by using the parameter `--output file_name`.

In the second part I'm trying to extract the content of the file into the indicated path. When run separately both work perfectly `git archive 0af62b1 --output file_name` followed by `tar -xf file_name -C /the/path/here/`.

Why piping is not possible in this case and how do I know if a certain command accepts piped input?

Comment: `f` requires a filename

Comment: Your `tar` command interprets `-C` as the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to pipe your `git` into  `tar -xf - -C /the/path/here/` where `-` is synonymous of the standard input. Or simpler `tar -xC /the/path/here` (`-` is the default file).

Comment: What the default file is depends on the `tar` implementation and version. With several implementations, it's still some tape device as `tar` is the `t`ape `a`rchiver. With GNU `tar`, it's determined at compile time (defaults to `-`), but can also be overriden with the `$TAPE` env var. I'd recommend to always using `-f -` to specify stdin.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is given in your error output:

$ git archive --format=tar 0af62b1 | tar **-xf -C** /the/path/here/
tar: **-C: Cannot open:** No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

You are telling tar to use a file named -C which does not exist and hence you get failure.

In working case, you are giving a file named file_name which exists and every thing works.

Possible fix : remove "-f -C" in the command.